# dos2unix not able to process files with /cygdrive in the path

Tags: cygwin

I recently switched computers (Windows 10 → Windows 10). I'm trying to set up the new computer as much like the old computer as possible.

I've used Cygwin on both machines with the same directory setup. However, on the old computer, I could execute:

```
dos2unix /cygdrive/c/path/myfile.php
```

and it would work fine. On the new computer, the same command gives:

```
dos2unix: Skipping /cygdrive/c/path/myfile.php, not a regular file.
```

However, if I `cd` to `/cygdrive/c/path` and execute `dos2unix myfile.php`, it works.

There's other weirdness too: `scp` and `rsync` can't find my SSH key file if the path includes `cygdrive`, but they can if I `cd` to the directory containing the key file and use a relative path.

What's wrong with my setup?

**UPDATE:**

Also, this is a weird thing that happens:

```
[my-name:~]$ mkdir /cygdrive/c/dir1

[my-name:~]$ mkdir /cygdrive/c/dir2

[my-name:~]$ touch /cygdrive/c/dir1/file.txt

[my-name:~]$ scp /cygdrive/c/dir1/file.txt /cygdrive/c/dir2/file.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Here's what's in my `$PATH`, as Cygwin sees it:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot/bin
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32
/cygdrive/c/Windows
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Roaming/nvm
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node_modules/.bin
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Roaming/npm
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/composer
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/git/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/git/cmd
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/git/mingw64/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/git/usr/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/laragon/utils
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/mysql/mysql-5.7.24-winx64/bin
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/nginx/nginx-1.16.0
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/ngrok
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/notepad++
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/putty
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/redis/redis-x64-3.2.100
/cygdrive/m/laragon/bin/telnet
/cygdrive/m/laragon/usr/bin
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/.windows-build-tools/python27
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Roaming/nvm
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs
/cygdrive/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PhpStorm 2021.1/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't have `dos2unix` and `openssh` specifically installed through Cygwin. I had them installed in other places in the OS, though, so when I'd try to execute `dos2unix`, it was using a version that was installed with Git Bash, which obviously didn't understand `/cygdrive`. I found that out with `which dos2unix`, etc. `scp` and `ssh` are both part of `openssh`. The solution was to reinstall Cygwin with those packages included.

Comment: Cygwin setup allow to add/remove packages. You don't need to `reinstall`

Comment: You have to run the setup-x86_64.exe file, which is basically the same thing to me.